# forms.ModelChoiceField - Как получить с помощью queryset=Name_model.objects.filter() объекты, созданные авторизованным пользователем?

Tags: django

```
**forms.py**

class KomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Kom
    fields = ('company', 'title',)

**models.py**

class Company(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Kom(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_
```

Подскажите, как можно при обращении к форме отфильтровать объекты Company так,
чтобы пользователь видел в поле ModelChoiceField только те компании (Company), которые создавал сам.

Благодаря бесценной помощи неравнодушных людей я решил эту задачу.
Правильным является совет Where Answer, единственно, пришлось поменять кое-что местами. Получилось вот так, и это работает:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
# вызываем конструктор формы и сохраняем пользователя
    if 'user' in kwargs and kwargs['user'] is not None:
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        qs = Company.objects.filter(author__id=user.id)
    super(KommpredForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
    self.fields['company'].queryset = qs
```

а в представлении необходимо указать вот так:

form = KommpredForm(request.POST, user=user)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте фильтр в поле формы, а пользователя в форму можно передать при создании.

```
class KomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Kom
        fields = ('company', 'title',)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if 'user' in kwargs and kwargs['user'] is not None:
           user = kwargs.pop('user')
           qs = Company.objects.filter(author__id=user.id)

       # вызываем конструктор формы и добавляет query set
       super(KomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       try:
           self.fields['company'].queryset = qs
       except NameError:
           pass

def your_view(request):
    user = request.user if request.user.is_authenticated() else None
    form = KomForm(user=user)
    return render('template.html' {'form': form})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не подскажете ли вы, как правильно использовать  self.user.id в данном случае. Я понимаю, что это возможно элементарные вещи, но я никак не могу понять, как получить авторизованного пользователя. По вашему примеру получаю ошибку: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Обновил ответ, должно работать

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь в решении вопроса. Но пока я получаю ошибку __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user' по предложенному вами решению. За это время я провел обширную исследовательскую работу, но видимо еще не заполнил все пробелы в понимании.

Comment: В вопросе я выложил что подправил немного, так что в целом вы дали отличный совет! Спасибо.

Comment: Хорошо) ответ поправил